# How to get a worldwide valid timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, meteor, timestamp

On my admin panel, I select a date from a Date input and send it to the server, which stores it in a MongoDB Date field. Before sending it, I change the date with a `setHour(23,59,59,999)`, so that the countdown ends at midnight (of whatever timezone, I do not care as long as it ends at the same moment for everyone in the world).

Then (I'm using Meteor), I query the fields, which is a Date object, I get its timestamp with a `.getTime()`, and every minute, thanks to a `setInterval`, I simply compute the time left with a new `Date()`, and output a `hh:mm` format.

*But*, when I put my PC on a different timezone, at the next interval computation, the value of time left is modified. And that's the same happening to my clients that are not in the same timezone, meaning the time left calculation is likely not done with absolute values.

Selecting the date:

```
Meteor.call("saveDate", new Date(new Date(t.find("#form_date").value).setHours(23,59,59,999)));
```

Saving it in mongo, server side:

```
saveDate: date => { DailyTopic.insert({ date: date }); };
```

Client calculation and display :

```
getTimeRemaining = function (limit) {
  let endTime = new Date(limit).setHours(23, 59, 59, 999),
      nowTime = Date.now();

  let t = endTime - nowTime;

  let seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 ),
      minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 ),
      hours   = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );

  return ({
    'hours'   : hours,
    'minutes' : minutes,
    'seconds' : seconds
  });
}

Template.debate.onCreated(function () {
  let self = this;

  self.timeLeft = new ReactiveVar(null);

  self.limit = getTodayTopic('fetch');

  self.interval = Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    self.timeLeft.set( getTimeRemaining( getTodayTopic('fetch').date ) );
  }, (1000 * 60));

  setTimeout(function () {
    self.timeLeft.set( getTimeRemaining( getTodayTopic('fetch').date ) );
  }, 3000);

});
 [...]

displayIimeLeft: function () {
    let time = Template.instance().timeLeft.get(),
        sp = " ";

    if (time) {
      return (time.hours + sp + TAPi18n.__('hours') + sp + time.minutes + sp + TAPi18n.__('minutes'));
    }
  }
...
```

But my problem is that the displayed countdown changes according to the client timezone when I need it to be the same everywhere in the world!

Comment: Javascript Dates use a UTC time value that represents milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. You can simply compare time values to see if one date is before or after another, regardless of the time zone of the host system. All you care about is the accuracy of the actual value, which is dependent on the accuracy of the host clock.

Comment: Yes, that's what I read everywhere, but as soon as I change my computer time zone, the countdown disappear ! That's why only the people that are close to the server are able to correctly see the countdown.

I'm in GMT+2, when I put my PC on UTC or GMT0, the countdown value is wrong and, if 'm close enough to the end time of the countdown, it simply dissapear.

Comment: I edited so that you can see what I having currently (I tried many other things before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a Date Object of the limit date from your server, as you tagged Javascript, it would be done like this:

```
var time = new Date();
```

Then, add whatever time you need to that date object, which is the current time.

After that, you can compare that Date Object (Which has your servers timezone) with your clients Date (with their timezone)

That could be easily done with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment(time).fromNow(); // E.g: in 24 Hours.
```

Actually this could be easily done without Moment.js too, but its up to you.
The only trick is comparing dates with timezones on them.

Comment: I did used that method from moment, but the problem is that I need a multilingual system. That's why, for the countdown, I'm looking for a hh--mm-ss format.

Comment: I edited so that you can see what I having currently (I tried many other things before)

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply counting down to a particular time, you don't even need to convert the time value to a date, you can just do:

```
var millisecondsLeft = timeValue - new Date();
```

and that's it. If the value is negative, then you're past the time represented by the time value.

If you pass the UTC time value that you wish to count down to, then on the host system you can create an equivalent date using `new Date(timeValue)`.

Using this method, the host time zone is only used to present a human readable string for output, it has no effect on the date's time value. If you use a method like *toISOString*, which is always GMT, then you will see exactly the same time on all hosts, regardless of their time zone setting.

So if you want to count down to, say, noon on 25 May, 2016 for a particular system then create a date on that system and get its time value:

```
var timeValue = new Date(2016, 4, 25, 12).getTime();
```

Now on any other system you can do:

```
var date = new Date(timeValue);
```

and you'll get a date for exactly the same instant in time (providing *timeValue* is a Number, not a string).

It's also easy to create a time value for a time in any time zone by simply applying the appropriate offset to either the time value or to the date object (using UTC methods) prior to getting the time value.

Comment: I edited so that you can see what I having currently (I tried many other things before)